# When does Batman get called the "Dark Knight"?

Tags: dc, batman, episode-identification, dc-animated-universe

I've started watching *Batman: The Animated Series* and I'm into the second season, I believe. There is an episode where Robin says that people call Batman "The Dark Knight", but I don't recall a time in that series where anyone has said that. When does someone (specifically in this series) refer to Batman as "The Dark Knight"?

Comment: Batman has been called the Dark Knight for many, many years in the comics.  Probably since shortly after his first appearance.

Comment: I'm wondering for this animated series specifically

Comment: It's not in-universe, but there is the episode of *The New Batman Adventures* called "Legends of the Dark Knight". Can't remember if he gets referred to by that name in the episode though

Comment: I don't know but it is an even better description of the character than Batman.

Comment: @Wad Cheber - I don't think the term goes back as far as his first appearance--it became really popular with Frank Miller's comic "The Dark Knight Returns", and [this wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frank_Miller_(comics)#Batman:_The_Dark_Knight_Returns_and_the_late_1980s) says Miller chose the title *'based upon him being called the "Darknight Detective" in some 1970s portrayals.'* Of course uncited claims in wikipedia aren't necessarily correct, but if the term was widely used earlier I'd think some comic fan would correct this statement.

Comment: ...also, [this reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/batman/comments/37axr2/who_invented_the_term_darknight_detective/) suggests the term may have been invented by Denny O'Neil in the 70s, and [this book](http://books.google.com/books?id=Mw_4AgAAQBAJ&lpg=PP1&pg=PR12) refers to "Denny O'Neil and Neal Adams' 'Darknight Detective' of the 1970s".

Comment: @Hypnosifl want to turn your comments into an answer?

Comment: @cocoa - I thought your question was just asking about when he was first called "The Dark Knight" in *Batman: The Animated Series*, are you also asking about the origin of the name in the comics?

Comment: @Hypnosifl yes that was my original intent, but if there is no reference in this series then the origin of the term works too

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found a set of transcripts of *Batman: The Animated Series* [here](http://www.springfieldspringfield.co.uk/episode_scripts.php?tv-show=batman), and used command-F (control-F on a PC) to search for "Dark Knight" in them. The episodes are listed out-of-order on that page, but looking at the production order [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Batman:_The_Animated_Series_episodes), it seems the term was first used in episode 15 of the first season, "The Cat and the Claw", when Catwoman said "So long, Dark Knight." It was also used in some other first-season episodes:

- In episode 18, "Beware the Gray Ghost", the Mad Bomber (a toy collector) says "Well, if it isn't the Dark Knight himself."
- In episode 22, "Joker's Favor", a character named Charlie says to the Joker "This is how it ends, Joker. No big schemes. No grand fight to the finish with the Dark Knight. Tomorrow, all the papers will say is that the great Joker was found blown to bits in an alley alongside a miserable little nobody."
- In episode 46, "Almost Got 'im", the Joker recounts a story in which he had captured Batman and put him on a phony talk show, where he introduced him with the line "We've got a real treat for you, kids. I ran into my first guest last night while making a withdrawal from the bank. You know him as 'the dark knight,' but we prefer to think of him as history. Here he is, the one and only Batman."
- In episode 48, "What is Reality?", Edward Nygma said "They call you the Dark Knight. Then you have to move like a knight."

The term didn't originated in the series though, it had been used in the comics previously. Prior to Christopher Nolan's film *The Dark Knight*, most people who knew the term would probably have associated it with Frank Miller's comic series [*The Dark Knight Returns*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Dark_Knight_Returns), which became one of the best-selling graphic novels of all time. [Miller's wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frank_Miller_(comics)#Batman:_The_Dark_Knight_Returns_and_the_late_1980s) says *'Miller created a tough, gritty Batman, referring to him as "The Dark Knight" based upon him being called the "Darknight Detective" in some 1970s portrayals.'* Someone on [this reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/batman/comments/37axr2/who_invented_the_term_darknight_detective/) suggests the term "Darknight Detective" probably was invented by Batman comic writer [Denny O'Neil](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dennis_O%27Neil) in the 1970s. The book *Hunting The Dark Knight: Twenty-First Century Batman* refers on p. xii (viewable on google books [here](http://books.google.com/books?id=Mw_4AgAAQBAJ&lpg=PP1&pg=PR12)) to *'"Denny O'Neil and Neal Adams' 'Darknight Detective' of the 1970s"'*, and another book on the history of Batman, *Batman Unauthorized: Vigilantes, Jokers, and Heroes in Gotham City* says on p. 20 (viewable on google books [here](http://books.google.com/books?id=VydBDR_aTgoC&lpg=PP1&pg=PA20)):

> However, it was as the camp television show was in its final days that
>   a writer named Denny O'Neil (born in the same month and year as Batman
>   himself, May 1939) took over the reigns of the comic book and changed
>   everything. Partnering with the soon-to-be-legendary artist Neal
>   Adams, who brought a hitherto unseen level of realism to the depiction
>   of superheroes, O'Neil revamped the Batman legend, either reinventing
>   the character or returning it to its 1939 roots, depending on your
>   perspective. Robin (who was previously presumed to be thirteen) was
>   swiftly aged and sent off to college. Gone mostly were the costumed
>   villains, replaced by international terrorists, corrupt politicians,
>   and mafia bosses. **O'Neil's Batman was a Darknight
>   Detective**—emphasis on "detective"—more akin to Sherlock Holmes than
>   a superhero, who employed his wits and credible criminology methods in
>   the apprehension of evildoers.

And [here](http://comicspriceguide.com/titles/darknight-detective/skuqi) is a comic from 1982 which uses "Darknight Detective" for a title.

edit: Thanks to JC2k8, who notes that [this wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dark_Knight_%28nickname%29) says the name "Dark Knight" actually dates to the first standalone Batman comic (after his initial origin in *Detective Comics*), [*Batman* No. 1](http://batman.wikia.com/wiki/Batman_Issue_1), from 1940. It seems it was in the debut story of the Joker, which is posted on [this site](http://thegreatcomicbookheroes.blogspot.com/2014/02/the-jokers-first-appearance-in-batman-1.html)...below is the final panel on [this page](http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-56z74kEjAyA/UuBu0BppCiI/AAAAAAAADOo/8qfZlgw2TRo/s1600/Batman+7.JPG) from that story (it was recently posted on the [twitter feed](https://twitter.com/MarcTNobleman) of Marc T. Nobleman, who wrote the book *Bill the Boy Wonder* about Batman co-creater Bill Finger that was referenced in the wikipedia article):

[image]

Perhaps the term had been out of usage for a long time before Denny O'Neil brought it back for his more gritty take on Batman?

Comment: Addendum: The term *Dark Knight* was coined in Batman No. 1 in 1940, according do [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dark_Knight_%28nickname%29), in a story written by Bill Finger.

Comment: *"the very first episode "The Cat and the Claw""* - Are you really sure that is the very first episode of *The Animated Series* (or maybe that isn't what you're saying in that sentence?)?

Comment: @TARS - It was listed first on the page but I see they're listed out-of-order there, I've corrected that sentence.

Comment: Awesome answer! Thanks so much!